# CPropertySheet / CPropertyPage : Remove gaps

Tags: mfc

I'm trying to modify `CPropertyPage`, `CTabCtrl`, and `CPropertySheet` to obtain a fully customized appearance for the three component mentioned previously, But this is what I was able to achieve :

[image: Unwanted Resualts]

However Somethings just don't go along and I want to remove them, but I don't seem a find a way to do it.

So I would like to get some help and propositions on how to achieve the following changes :

1. Change the color of the title bar.
2. Remove the gabs between : CPropertyPage and CTabCtrl / CPropertySheet and CPropertySheet.

you will find below, an image describing the things I want to remove and modify.

[image: Unwanted Resualts]

Comment: That's referring to the [nonclient area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/nonclient-area) of a window. You need to render it, too, or remove it when you receive a [WM_NCCALCSIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-nccalcsize) message.